Certain elements not loading in my react-native view
So I have this object Community. Users can create communities and on a page I want them to be able to filter either their communities or all communities. Now when I load the app for the first time and I go to all communities I see all of them like I want it to. Then I go over to My Communities and I see all my communities also like i want it to. Now when I go back to All communities without reloading the app I only see the Communities which are not mine so I don't see all of them just the ones where Im not part of and I have no idea what is causing this behaviour.
This is my react-native component.
function CommunityContent() {
    const [myCommunities, setMyCommunities] = useState([]);
    const [allCommunities, setAllCommunities] = useState([]);
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [myCommunity, setMyCommunity] = useState(false);
    const [userID, setUserID] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerTitle: 'Communities',
        });
        fetchUserInfo();
    }
    , []);

    useEffect(() => {
        handleCommunityChange();
    }, [myCommunity]);


    async function fetchUserInfo() {
        const userInfo = await currentSession();
        const userName =  userInfo.idToken.payload['cognito:username']
        setUserID(userName)
    }

    async function handleCommunityChange() {
        if (myCommunity) {
            await handleMyCommunities();
        } else {
            await handleAllCommunities();
        }
    }
    

    async function handleMyCommunities() {
        try {
            setMyCommunity(true);
            const myCommunities = await getCommunitiesByUserID(userID);
            setMyCommunities(myCommunities.data.communitiesByUserID.items);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error fetching my communities:", error);
        }
    }

    async function handleAllCommunities(){
        try {
            setMyCommunity(false);
            const allCommunities = await getAllCommunities();
            console.log('All communities:', allCommunities.data.listCommunities.items);
            setAllCommunities(allCommunities.data.listCommunities.items);
        }catch (error) {
            console.log("Error fetching all communities:", error);
        }
    }

    function renderItem({ item }) {
        return (
            <CommunityCard
                data={item}
            />
        );
    }


    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <View style={styles.filterContainer}>
                <View>
                    <FlatButton
                        onPress={handleAllCommunities}
                    >
                        All communities
                    </FlatButton>
                    <View style={!myCommunity ? styles.selectedCommunity : styles.notSelectedCommunity}>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <FlatButton
                        onPress={handleMyCommunities}
                    >
                        My communities
                    </FlatButton>
                    <View style={myCommunity ? styles.selectedCommunity : styles.notSelectedCommunity}>
                    </View>
                    
                </View>
            </View>
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={myCommunity ? myCommunities : allCommunities}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

Also when I log either only My Communities or All communities I see all the correct data coming in.
If any extra information in needed please ask so in the comments and ill try to provide it as fast as possible. Im looking forward to hearing everyones insights!
